# warning: no inet socket available: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, localhost, chroot, ifconfig, proc

so there i am using chroot to chrooting into debian bootstrap everything worked just right on root account until i added a new user to figure out that i cannot do update or access xdisplay or localhost ip which is strange i did not know what to do so i am asking for help
here is the chroot script i am using

```
~ $ cat chroot.sh
sudo mount -t proc /proc chroot-ubuntu/proc
sudo mount --rbind /sys chroot-ubuntu/sys
sudo mount --rbind /dev chroot-ubuntu/dev
sudo mount /system/ chroot-ubuntu/system/
unset LD_PRELOAD
env -i HOME=/root \
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/wine-5.3/bin/:/opt/wine-staging/bin/" \
TERM="xterm" \
BASH="/usr/bin/bash" \
SHELL="/usr/bin/bash" \
PREFIX="/usr" \
MDIR="/tmp" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/:/var/lib:/var/lib/dpkg/:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib:/opt/wine-stable/lib:/opt/wine-stable/lib/wine:/opt/wine-5.3/lib:/lib:/lib/wine:/lib/wine/fakedlls:/opt/wine-staging/lib" \
chroot  chroot-ubuntu/   /bin/bash
```

i execute chroot.sh using sudo so iam always into root account
lets add a new user i get this strange output

```
root@localhost:~# adduser  g
Adding user `g' ...
Adding new group `g' (1000) ...
Adding new user `g' (1000) with group `g' ...
Creating home directory `/home/g' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
passwd: user 'g' does not exist
Permission denied
Try again? [y/N]
```

and if i try to add a password to the new user i get

```
root@localhost:~# passwd  g
passwd: user 'g' does not exist
```

so o had to add user manually which i did (i dont remember how)

here is the ifconfig output on root and user

```
root@localhost:~# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
```

notice that inet 127.0.0.1 which not there when do ifcnfig on user

```
spiral@localhost:~$ /sbin/ifconfig
warning: no inet socket available: No such file or directory`
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
```

instead there is `warning: no inet socket available: No such file or directory` error

Comment: I went digging through the source code of Linux ifconfig (net-tools) to find out where the error message comes from, and wasn't able to understand what causes it, but would very much like to unsee the Linux 2.2-era horrors that were found. Please switch to `ip addr` already...

Comment: Can you run ifconfig under `strace` and see which system call returns ENOENT?

Comment: thank you for your time i did reinstall the bootatrap and i cant add a user again @user1686

Answer (score 0):

here is the output

```
spiral@localhost:~$ strace ifconfig  2>&1 |grep ENOENT
proot warning: ptrace request 'PTRACE_???' not supported yet
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ax25", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                           faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/nr", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/rose", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ipx", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                            faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/appletalk", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/net/econet", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/net/ash", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/x25", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ax25", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/nr", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/rose", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ipx", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/appletalk", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/net/econet", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/net/ash", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/x25", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
spiral@localhost:~$
```